# Clean python and git install, admin or user? MacOS

Tags: python, git, installation

I'm looking to set up python on a new machine.

I've found many instructions on this however I'm concerned with keeping the main installation clean so that each future environment can be modified specifically while I become familiar with the ins and outs of the program and packages.

I've installed python and git on my old machine and having not really known anything I did all the installs via the admin account and made all settings global.

Later discovered this was likely not the best way to do it.

I wonder if anyone here might be able to point this crayon eater in the right direction?

Would I be best off to make a user account on the computer specifically for my developing projects and install python, git, etc locally on this profile? Or are there parts of the install which one would want to have installed from the admin account?

Comment: Have you considered using [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is OK to have `git` installed globally. Just create a new repository for each project, using `git init`.

For maintaining python dependencies per project, consider using `virtualenv` or `pyenv`. They create virtual environments which can be activated and deactivated and keep you from cluttering up your globally install python packages.

An alternative is to create a Docker image for each project and run your projects inside Docker containers.

If you are a beginner, the latter might be an overkill.